# How to properly add some new arguments in a subclass?

Tags: python

I am trying to subclass `list` in order to implement a callback function that would be called whenever a list item is being set.

I have this:

```
class CustomList(list):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.setitem_callback = kwargs['setitem_callback']
        del kwargs['setitem_callback']
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __setitem__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__setitem__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setitem_callback()

def callback():
    print('callback')



 l = ['a', 'b', 'c']
 custom_list = CustomList(l, setitem_callback=callback)
 custom_list[1] = 'd' # prints 'callback'
```

It works as expected, but I am concerned about having to do `del kwargs['setitem_callback']` in order for the superclass' `__init__` to work. Is it a bad practice? Are there any other ways to achieve the same?

Comment: Your indentation is broken, you will have lots of `SyntaxError`s. Yes it's possible as you can just do `def foo(*args, my_important_argument, **kwargs):`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Peilonrayz said in the comments: You can just write

```
class CustomList(list):
    def __init__(self, *args, setitem_callback, **kwargs):
        self.setitem_callback = setitem_callback
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __setitem__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__setitem__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setitem_callback()

def callback():
    print('callback')

l = ['a', 'b', 'c']
custom_list = CustomList(l, setitem_callback=callback)
custom_list[1] = 'd' # prints 'callback'
```

as long as you're okay with slightly different behavior when the caller forgets to pass `setitem_callback=` at all. With your original code, you get a KeyError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 16, in <module>
    custom_list = CustomList(l)
  File "test.py", line 3, in __init__
    self.setitem_callback = kwargs['setitem_callback']
KeyError: 'setitem_callback'
```

With a proper keyword argument, you get a `TypeError` with a more tailored message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 16, in <module>
    custom_list = CustomList(l)
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'setitem_callback'
```